# XCode setting to see code which won't work on previous OS versions

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've written an app specifically for iOS7, and am now attempting to make it work for iOS6.

I'd really like a setting to enable warnings which highlight lines of code which won't work on iOS6.  i.e. any calls to code which ONLY work on iOS7.

That way I can immediately identify any lines of code which I need to attend to before catching them during debugging.

Does this even exist?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The only way is to run your app under iOS6 and thoroughly debug and look for crashes.

Comment: try to set deployment target to iOS 6

Comment: @Volker how will that produce the warnings?

Comment: @Volker That doesn't change anything, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two option to deal with this.

1. Use [MJGAvailability](https://github.com/mattjgalloway/MJGFoundation/blob/master/Source/Utilities/MJGAvailability.h), a drop in header file and it will make warnings if a selector is "too new".
2. Buy [Delpoymate](http://www.deploymateapp.com), it can scan your Xcode project and show you any incompatible calls.

If you use an older Xcode next to the newest, than use this snippet:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(newSelector)]){
#if __IPHONE_7_0
      [self newSelector];
#endif
} else {
      [self oldSelector];
}
```

Comment: MJGAvailability FTW!  Thanks Tuss!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of getting a warning to appear and even if there was how would the `IDE` now that you would have done something to handle it like the below

```
if([myObject respondsToSelect:@selector(myiOS7SelectorOnly)]) {
    [myObject myiOS7SelectorOnly];
}
```

It works the other way if you where developing an app for iOS7 and you used a deprecated method that iOS7 API doesn't use any more it would give you a warning but not the other way you will have to wait for it to turn around and crash and throw an `unrecognised selector` exception.

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate a warning might not be right "tactic" for addressing this. But I do think there is a use case for identifying lines of code which won't work with a certain OS version.

Comment: Is there a way of temporarily setting the BaseSDK to iOS6?  Would that   work?  I only have iOS7 as an option so can't try it.

Comment: Yes, I can see there being a need for it but unfortunately it only does it the other way not the way you are wanting. You could search for an unofficial plugin for xcode but I'm not sure what exactly you would search for.

Comment: You might be able to download the iOS 6 sdk from the apple developer area on the apple website, but I'm not sure. As far as Apple are concerned it should only work one way not the other and they do this by marking things as deprecated, this is how it is in a lot of programming languages not just objective-c

Answer (score 0):

At some point I had 2 Xcode installed - Xcode 4 and Xcode 5. Xcode 4 did not have API for ios7 and it was showing all incompatibilities.
But I don't know where can you find XCode4 now and will it still show errors in ios7 code or not?
At least you can try this way.

Comment: That's not going to go to get rid of the warnings once you have handled them though. Also I believe you can develop iOS 7 in xcode 4 as long as xcode 5 is installed as it will use the same libraries (This is only here-say I have never tried it).

Comment: Sure, warnings and errors will stay. I did not compile using XCode4, I used it only for checking what may be wrong.
Question asks to get some way to see possible error places automatically and xcode4 may help with it

Comment: I'm not sure it would, but I'm not downvoting as it would be to much effort to find out if you are wrong or not I will leave that up to the OP to do.