# App crashes in iOS 5 and works fine in iOS 6 and 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5

App works fine in iOS 6 and 7 but crashes in iOS 5. It is a universal app. I have two main xibs for iPhone and iPad. No storyboards used.

App crashes before even entering appdidfinishlauching.

I have enabled zombie and added all exceptions breakpoint. Deployment target is 4.3

Below is the device log:

```
Incident Identifier: 14891C05-C32F-4CCF-8FEB-40C9CA7E96DC
CrashReporter Key:   49d2b30dde0356b299db9b8c203e94776a42688c
Hardware Model:      iPad1,1
Process:         xyz [2770]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/0B5060DD-1F41-42DA-AB0A-               
CB0D361D5531/xyz.app/xyz
Identifier:      xyz
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2014-02-09 03:52:26.860 +0530
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000010
Crashed Thread:  0
`
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   xyz                     0x002978e0 cr_detectClasses + 112
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33466ae2 call_load_methods + 82
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x334668d4 load_images + 120
3   dyld                            0x2fea77ca dyld::notifySingle(dyld_image_states, ImageLoader const*) + 146
4   dyld                            0x2feb0854  ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 300
5   dyld                            0x2feb1826 ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 34
6   dyld                            0x2fea8a3a dyld::initializeMainExecutable() + 266
7   dyld                            0x2feacc16 dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**) + 1430
8   dyld                            0x2fea72c8 dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*) + 572
9   dyld                            0x2fea7058 _dyld_start + 48

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00510790      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000000
r4: 0x002e8914    r5: 0x00000036      r6: 0x000000e6      r7: 0x2fea4cb0
r8: 0x003242ec    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x0050d800     r11: 0x2fea4d10
ip: 0x005109d0    sp: 0x2fea4c9c      lr: 0x35798cb9      pc: 0x002978e0
cpsr: 0x80000030

    Binary Images:
0xaa000 -   0x2e5fff +xyz armv7  <06ccd52f58813485b533a0b3c964985a> /var/mobile/Applications/0B5060DD-1F41-42DA-AB0A-CB0D361D5531/xyz.app/xyz
0x2fea6000 - 0x2fec7fff  dyld armv7  <77eddfd654df393ba9c95ff01715fd08> /usr/lib/dyld
0x3032c000 - 0x303dffff  iTunesStore armv7  <b3c0cce5f8e632e18f841c32b68f57a1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStore.framework/iTunesStore
0x303e4000 - 0x30467fff  MapKit armv7  <e39706ac199134a497954e1f1d6d7245> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x30468000 - 0x3046efff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x3056c000 - 0x30580fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <54091a638f8731cd85ccf00fa06972c3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x306b4000 - 0x30711fff  StoreServices armv7  <6ce256d3cf433e4aa1af8d696bf1f75d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x30712000 - 0x3075efff  CoreTelephony armv7  <b8f80d5d594c31d2b5d8fba9fdedb7e1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x30780000 - 0x307b8fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x307b9000 - 0x307e5fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <3aacc5b650e037c086a8ff6657d154bf> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x30d80000 - 0x30dd1fff  CoreText armv7  <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x30dd2000 - 0x30dd6fff  CertUI armv7  <f503892ef60e36108d28d8f9d6144d2a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x30e42000 - 0x30e42fff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x30e43000 - 0x30e59fff  EAP8021X armv7  <952fcfdec0633aff923768fca1a26fcb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x30e5a000 - 0x30e6ffff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x3112c000 - 0x31149fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x3114f000 - 0x312c2fff  MediaPlayer armv7  <63cdf8f9c66d36e7a4e69e2f6cae854f> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x31479000 - 0x31479fff  vecLib armv7  <a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x314df000 - 0x314eefff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <70ac33720f513f0f97ea2279260678ca> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x314fb000 - 0x315d2fff  CFNetwork armv7  <765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x315d3000 - 0x315f3fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x31657000 - 0x31884fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <c3098478486032c6aff336fa711c4fc6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x3189d000 - 0x318aafff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x318b6000 - 0x318b6fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <eb82984fa36c329387aa518aa5205f3d> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x31aa8000 - 0x31fecfff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <f326d88709683520b251dc53cb847c11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x31fed000 - 0x31ff0fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <f5cc4b97ce9432da9426f12621453325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x31ff1000 - 0x32002fff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <ccf25b1e49ce3b2fa58d8c8546755505> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x32003000 - 0x32008fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x32037000 - 0x3205bfff  PrintKit armv7  <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x3205c000 - 0x320bffff  IMCore armv7  <046b6b615a743057b59d4aaba8a91d61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x320d9000 - 0x320dbfff  MobileInstallation armv7  <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x320ea000 - 0x3212dfff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <95b49daf4cf038b6bea8010bba3a1e26> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x324b8000 - 0x324bcfff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d6a7436ed8dc33d795c9b42baf864882> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x3251c000 - 0x32522fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <e1f06241ef0e3f0aae00f15df572077e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x32629000 - 0x3262cfff  CoreTime armv7  <a398de5ba1e43a11b7008e9bb5a7f6fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x32636000 - 0x3263afff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x32698000 - 0x326ddfff  GeoServices armv7  <a26be2e76e8730ab91a16502aba376be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x326de000 - 0x326eafff  CoreVideo armv7  <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x326ef000 - 0x326f5fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x326f6000 - 0x3272afff  MIME armv7  <d30292ea8f7e360fa5f5d5b1b62b602d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x3272d000 - 0x32737fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x32743000 - 0x32805fff  Celestial armv7  <19617260ee073e23b95e456d93930aea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x32927000 - 0x3295cfff  DataAccess armv7  <89fd0c22338b37538cf61803a0bca9e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x3295d000 - 0x3295efff  DataMigration armv7  <d77f0e8f39ee37f5a2ac713a3fd9e693> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x3296d000 - 0x32a5efff  QuartzCore armv7  <35d64a9da5523ae08c9e41511fd3061b> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x32a5f000 - 0x32a70fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <e6144ba265da3bb7b9a263aa1a29b054> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x32a71000 - 0x32a94fff  MobileSync armv7  <e42604c550283f4aa517ae8f108b340f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x32ac1000 - 0x32ad7fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x32b08000 - 0x32caefff  CoreData armv7  <b0215b6d4d143859a2b313ecade095ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x32caf000 - 0x32cbefff  OpenGLES armv7  <e80acc691001301e96101bb89d940033> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x32cbf000 - 0x32cc4fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <dc11c5c2cbe73a6288a6094ebf5de673> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x32cc5000 - 0x32ccafff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x32f02000 - 0x32f06fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x32f43000 - 0x32f44fff  CoreSurface armv7  <97f871f09f503c98a6371c2b657430d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x32f45000 - 0x333e7fff  UIKit armv7  <cd513a2f22f53d698c3e10f6fe48a63e> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x33463000 - 0x33529fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x33535000 - 0x3353ffff  GraphicsServices armv7  <cb64e146a8ee3fda9e80ffae1ccc9c5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x33579000 - 0x335f8fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <bf01f5ed47b033d8bde30d735ff44416> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3369d000 - 0x3369dfff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <a80aaa9989483ce3a496a061fd1e9e0a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x336e1000 - 0x336f0fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d84c3fd0e7bd36e78c256f2f4c5a4e91> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x336f7000 - 0x336fafff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <e52b77623bd031bc807e77029566c777> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x336fb000 - 0x33711fff  DictionaryServices armv7  <6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x3371a000 - 0x33726fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <bdb2b4d1a78c39c1ba60d791207aed2a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x33727000 - 0x3375cfff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x33778000 - 0x33797fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x33798000 - 0x338bdfff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x33b11000 - 0x33b5bfff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <f1fbb825def23043830a095b953a9c94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x33b82000 - 0x33bbefff  IMFoundation armv7  <253125b9103c3d13b66923ac6893c25b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x33bd5000 - 0x33bebfff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x33bec000 - 0x33c5cfff  CoreImage armv7  <86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x33c5d000 - 0x33c61fff  Marco armv7  <8dea3e558fe534ff868fc92e215ce53b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x33c85000 - 0x33caefff  AppleAccount armv7  <2ba44023410231fcb3f72f762ea3ce6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x33cb7000 - 0x33d50fff  EventKit armv7  <d67aa1508ee7306b8e2a45c76ffddff0> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x33d55000 - 0x33d91fff  AppSupport armv7  <311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x33e06000 - 0x340c7fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x34107000 - 0x3417bfff  MediaControlSender armv7  <87315c54b2293ab589950341ff91b45d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x341b6000 - 0x341c5fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <a2363f8ed49932dba415d2d4cd32fb74> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x341e1000 - 0x341e1fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <e0a73a57795f3e1698a52ebe6fc07005> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x341e2000 - 0x34327fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x34328000 - 0x34333fff  AccountSettings armv7  <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x34334000 - 0x3437dfff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x34519000 - 0x345e9fff  WebKit armv7  <3c5dd2ec46fe3e189c25bba78ad88fa1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x34881000 - 0x34927fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <da424fecc66e3628ab03378ae80b38fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x349ba000 - 0x349bdfff  ActorKit armv7  <434c756a6b053f4ba3c954cfccddbf59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x349e9000 - 0x349eafff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x34a59000 - 0x34ae5fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <f859ce1ad1773f0ba98d7c6e135b7697> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x34af9000 - 0x34afafff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <6a8f2f33c7543808a0f4599101c3b61a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x34b2c000 - 0x34b2ffff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <356cb66612e836968ef24e6e5c3364cc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x34bb3000 - 0x34bc4fff  AirTraffic armv7  <c9eb888c1bd1322cbda5b01d41be0c7d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirTraffic.framework/AirTraffic
0x34bd3000 - 0x34d51fff  Foundation armv7  <c40ddb073142315bb4ebb214343d0b7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x34d64000 - 0x34d6afff  IAP armv7  <17eddbf5590d3cb88d4acbda27447f5b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x34dcf000 - 0x34de6fff  WebBookmarks armv7  <696bb0630b19388da0d72e685bcf6e28> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x34e09000 - 0x34e39fff  ContentIndex armv7  <7a64670bb2ff3ee39ddee1dc1c72f92d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x34e63000 - 0x34e6ffff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <36ce86a3dc8c344596c8c325615f374b> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x34e8c000 - 0x34e8ffff  NetworkStatistics armv7  <7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x34e90000 - 0x35074fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <c91e27850452330ea804db6408840fd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x350b0000 - 0x350b7fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <bab4dcbfc5943d3fbb637342d35e8045> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x350bb000 - 0x350fbfff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x350fc000 - 0x35101fff  ApplePushService armv7  <f424c0340de637c08bbeb4f3bd8c6eaf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x35102000 - 0x3514afff  CoreMedia armv7  <e274e1b894753b2eb05cf7b22a36d0c1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x35186000 - 0x351d4fff  CoreLocation armv7  <44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x35258000 - 0x3525efff  MobileIcons armv7  <ed1b46f917903c9b9baaa2be4392dafe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x35279000 - 0x3527afff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x352a5000 - 0x352effff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x3569e000 - 0x3569ffff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x356e4000 - 0x35722fff  IOKit armv7  <fcda71d29d6136dfbd84c1725f4998e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x35740000 - 0x35746fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x35747000 - 0x3577efff  Security armv7  <eea56f71fde83c2981f9281dc7823725> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x3578f000 - 0x358a6fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x358ad000 - 0x358c3fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <311f379a9fde305d80c1b22b7dd2e52a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x358eb000 - 0x3597dfff  HomeSharing armv7  <11ca6ed6f8c0377aba1d3e03484c380f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x35997000 - 0x35a41fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <bf822cc1a3243ae7b104cf73ca22d352> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x35a72000 - 0x35b28fff  AVFoundation armv7  <35cb7a0eb1dc3554a777c1cc11cb0415> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x35cde000 - 0x35d03fff  OpenCL armv7  <f4b08361179a3f6bb033415b0d7c6251> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x35d09000 - 0x35d48fff  QuickLook armv7  <802b1092542a3017a0380632502610d4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x35d64000 - 0x35d68fff  FTClientServices armv7  <21de970d7ebb3e7fb502a0a5451b0806> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x35e54000 - 0x35e5efff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d>  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x35e8c000 - 0x35f7afff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x35f7d000 - 0x35f81fff  IOSurface armv7  <443ac3aab9283da480dd9dcda3c5c88e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x360d3000 - 0x36181fff  Message armv7  <573d0118246d3d9d8aed17e7ee2faec7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x36350000 - 0x36350fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <ebd2dddf55d83cf48a18913968775960> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x36351000 - 0x36354fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <b2c05d8601c13be884097192dca4e187> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x3647d000 - 0x364c6fff  AddressBook armv7  <b17a2962e9043e0385c3c2c652155f2b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x364c7000 - 0x36610fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <b70646b63f1f3b33896dd8cb91b8dab1> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3661a000 - 0x366a0fff  CoreMotion armv7  <6a9355d5a8e238b5b8f193605d509e15> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x366ce000 - 0x366cffff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x36725000 - 0x3677dfff  CoreAudio armv7  <be335e8eb6f93594b028a6ddd503a183> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x3677e000 - 0x36796fff  Notes armv7  <724966ed5cd4395cb70f9c996b123f53> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x36797000 - 0x36844fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x36845000 - 0x368a9fff  MessageUI armv7  <da7af4f9494b35558bf7892dfdb36ee3> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
 0x369a6000 - 0x369eafff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
 0x36a0e000 - 0x36a31fff  Bom armv7  <c3435ecd2e5839f89de51edad0e1bb00> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
 0x36a32000 - 0x36a36fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
 0x36a37000 - 0x36a37fff  Accelerate armv7  <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
 0x36a89000 - 0x36a8dfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
 0x36a8e000 - 0x36ae4fff  GMM armv7  <6b2f7e1aa6be3d69b4c4cf54ed960602> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
 0x36ae5000 - 0x36b5efff  ProofReader armv7  <6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
 0x36b61000 - 0x36d1efff  ImageIO armv7  <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
 0x36d41000 - 0x36d48fff  MailServices armv7  <ab2388ce733e38b7a261273a401bbbf1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
 0x36e6d000 - 0x36ebefff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <c352af5a742e3c7a8d4d7e5f6f454793> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
 0x3728c000 - 0x373c3fff  MusicLibrary armv7  <32bc794969e534df97a14dc4be228408> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
 0x373c6000 - 0x373c8fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <d4d4aa3090c83e87bcb15ed00b93fd5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
 0x373c9000 - 0x37405fff  iCalendar armv7  <f2836083051132d3aa40ad82d7f73aea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
 0x3743b000 - 0x37bfafff  WebCore armv7  <2690c38c9c5f3c09975d619dd1dfbed7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
 0x37c3c000 - 0x37c79fff  FTServices armv7  <3f23418319a03a589dd5cac7df20e238> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
 0x37d8a000 - 0x37d91fff  MediaRemote armv7  <42dc1b43dabd3692b97d6aacfbdf0449> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
 0x37d92000 - 0x37d9afff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
 0x37dcc000 - 0x37dd5fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
 0x37ddd000 - 0x37de5fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
 0x37de6000 - 0x37ebefff  vImage armv7  <caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
 0x37ee4000 - 0x37eebfff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <38132ecfd74b325fb1a4142bab663c19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
```

Below is the screenshot for the crash. The console has nothing logged.

[image]

Appdelegate code for appdifinishLaunching:

```
 if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
    //some iOS 7 stuff
       [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent ];
}

[application setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];


[[ UIApplication sharedApplication ] setIdleTimerDisabled: YES ];
checkForLogin = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
AppDelegateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSUserDefaults *storeData=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[storeData setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"APICALL"];
Appdate* appdate = [Appdate appdateWithAppleId:abcdefg];
appdate.delegate = self;
#if NS_BLOCKS_AVAILABLE
[appdate checkNowWithBlock: ^(NSError* error, NSDictionary* appInfo, BOOL updateAvailable) {
    if (!error)
    {

    }
}];
#endif
loginRegViewControllerobj=[[LoginRegViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginRegViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginRegViewControllerobj]autorelease];
[navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
[self.window setRootViewController:navController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[self.window becomeFirstResponder];
[Crittercism enableWithAppID:@"abcgkajhdkjasasd"
                 andDelegate:loginRegViewControllerobj];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"filestopbg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ive got a feeling its to do with Auto-layouts, have a look at my answer [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529513/why-does-this-code-crash-in-ios-5-1-but-not-ios-6/16529585#16529585)

Comment: Might as well be a library that doesn't support iOS5.0 anymore. Which xCode are you using? What SDK are you compiling with?

Comment: I am using Xcode 5.0.

Comment: Are you sure you not use any incompatible selectors? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21457096/1293167

Comment: @TussLászló You can tell from the log that it is nothing to do with incompatible selectors. Notice `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` this says it has tried to access something that it isn't allowed to access more then likely because it has been released from memory already.

Comment: I think it might as well be because of the SDK he is compiling with. He is trying to access a property (or method) that is available in ios6/7 but not in 5.

Comment: @TotumusMaximus If this was the case they wouldn't be getting a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` they would be getting an `NSInvalidArgumentException` for the exception type.

Comment: Please put your appdelegate didfinishlonching code;

Comment: I have added the appdidfinishinglaunching in the description. But the app crashes before entering appdidfinishlaunching.@BhaveshNai

Comment: @user1899840 How do you know it crashes before this what have you done?

Comment: @Popeye I added a break point in appdidfinishlaunching but it didn't enter at all, even when i tested in device.

Comment: Well there isn't much else we can do then it's all down to you - sorry.

Comment: @user1899840 Since you're seeing the debugger stopping saying `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, it has actually halted your program's execution before it would have a chance to print out a message to the console that might provide you with some details about the crash reason. Try clicking the "Continue" button in Xcode to have it continue execution until the program actually finishes crashing. You might have to do that a few times. It should hopefully spit out an error message stating what exactly the issue was.

Answer (score 2):

It is very hard (if not impossible) to tell from your log what exactly is causing the issue but we can tell what sort of error it is. It is throwing a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception which is basically an error in your memory management.

The best way to debug this is to turn zombie tools (NSZombieEnabled) on. This is located in `xcode` >> `Product` >> `Scheme` >> `Edit Scheme` >> `Diagnostics` and check the check box `Enable Zombie Objects`.

What EXC_BAD_ACCESS is saying is that you did something that caused a pointer to be de-referenced and that memory location isn’t inside one of the chunks of memory assigned to your program.

This could be because

> 1. The pointer used to point to memory that was ok, but its chunk was deallocated.
> 2. The pointer is corrupt.

In simple terms you are trying to access something that has been deallocated from memory. Unfortunately we don't know where this is from what you have posted. So for you, you need to be doing so debugging to replicate this issue. That is all you we can't help with that.

Comment: Thank you. But i have done that and m still getting the same crash. I have no idea wat is wrong..

Comment: Like I have said from the log that you have provide we can't tell you much except what sort of issue this is and how you may go about solving it. As for solving it you are going to have to put the time and effort in as we haven't got your app or your code so it is impossible for us to know where this error is. Like I say it is all down to you now there is nothing else we can tell you.

Comment: @user1899840 So does anything else get logged in the console as a result of having zombies enabled? Doing this isn't going to magically fix your code but should help you further identify the issue. Also have you looked at symbolicating the crash log?

Comment: @Luke i have no idea about the crash.I checked enabled zombies. I have another older version of the app that launches in iOS 5 as well. But after i have adde new xibs its crashing.